# Image slider - Unable to make images links without ruining positioning

Tags: css, image, slider, position

I have made an image slider that works fine until I try and make the images into links.
I have tried several things but all come up with different problems.

For instance when I change

```
<img src="img/radish.jpg" alt="radish">
```

to

```
<a href ="radish.html"><img src="img/radish.jpg" alt="radish"></a>
```

The image dissapears this can be fixed from changing

```
.slider li input:checked ~ img{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

To

```
.slider li input:checked ~ img a{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

However the image is not a click-able link still again I have found a way to fix this by adding

```
.slider li input:checked ~ a{
position: absolute;
}
```

but after doing this my label goes from the bottom of the slider to above the slider which I just don't know how to fix.

Below is the HTML and CSS before attempting to change the images to links.If someone could help me find a way to make the images links without changing the positions of any elements I will be forever in your debt thanks Bashtoe

HTML

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li>    
        <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide">
        <label for="slide1"></label>
        <img src="img/carrot.jpg" alt="carrot">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide" checked>
        <label for="slide2"></label>
        <img src="img/turnip.jpg" alt="turnip">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide">
        <label for="slide3"></label>
        <img src="img/radish.jpg" alt="radish">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide4" name="slide">
        <label for="slide4"></label>
        <img src="img/parsnip.jpg" alt ="parsnip">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide5" name="slide">
        <label for="slide5"></label>
        <img src="img/leek.jpg" alt="leek">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="slide6" name="slide">
        <label for="slide6"></label>
        <img src="img/onion.jpg" alt="onion">
    </li>

</ul>
```

Relevant CSS

```
.slider{
height: 480px;
width: 1000px;
padding-bottom: 3.5em;
padding-top: 0.4em;
padding-left:6.2em;
margin:0 auto;
}

.slider li{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; 
    /*Creates a two bordered effect*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #3C7F1E, 0px 0px 0px 6px #4C1F0A; 
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px 3px #3C7F1E, 0px 0px 0px 6px #4C1F0A;
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px 3px #3C7F1E, 0px 0px 0px 6px #4C1F0A;
}

.slider img{
    height: 480px;
    width: 800px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.slider input{
    display:none;
}
.slider label{
    background-color:#3C7F1E;
    bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white; /*Gives the button an outer ring */
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white; /*cross browser compatibility */
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
   -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px white;
   /*makes the buttons circular */
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   -o-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
}

.slider li input:checked ~ label{ /*Changes the color of the checked box */
    background: #4C1F0A;

}
/*Sets the distance from the left for the corrisponding button */
.slider li:nth-child(1) label{
    left: 16px;
}

.slider li:nth-child(2) label{
    left: 64px;
}

.slider li:nth-child(3) label{
    left: 112px;    
}
.slider li:nth-child(4) label{
    left: 160px;
}
.slider li:nth-child(5) label{
    left: 208px;
}
.slider li:nth-child(6) label{
    left: 256px;
}

/* Hides the images*/
.slider img{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*Displays the images when radio buttons are checked, note that the first starts as checked in the html*/
.slider li input:checked ~ img{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/5fCf8/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help - problem solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding:

```
.slider li input:checked ~ a{
position: absolute;
}
```

add some height to li ... for example

```
.slider li{
list-style: none;
position: absolute; 
height: 480px;
/*Creates a two bordered effect*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #3C7F1E, 0px 0px 0px 6px #4C1F0A; 
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 0px 3px #3C7F1E, 0px 0px 0px 6px #4C1F0A;
box-shadow:         0px 0px 0px 3px #3C7F1E, 0px 0px 0px 6px #4C1F0A;
}
```

This should fix position of the label

Comment: This worked! Allllllways the simple things that getcha!
Thank you sooooo much !